# What is the C# constant for "application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument" mimetype?

Tags: c#, content-type, xps

For "text/html" the following works:

`System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html`

Comment: Thank you for that question-answer, I found out what is the constant of pdf ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a built in constant in the current .NET Framework BCL. There are many MIME types that don't have a constant there.

Answer (score 1):

The framework just provides some basic/generic commonly used media types. The list of vendor specific MIME types changes too frequently for these to be burned into the framework so you'll need to do this one yourself.